# Google Map Marker with custom background and text

Tags: android, google-maps, android-custom-view, marker, nine-patch

I'm trying to customize an map marker so that it can be displayed with 3 main features:

- 9patch drawable as background
- Custom text
- Optional drawable to the left of the text (some markers have it, some don't)

I have used **IconGenerator** from **android google map utils library**, but somehow the entire clickable area of the marker is affected. An very big area around the marker is clickable and activates the marker. It also has issues with the content padding and gravity attributes.

I have added the custom hack on the map in order to bring to front the markers without opening the info window (I've setup an info window with no content to display and I've called showInfoWindow in Marker click event listener).

How can I manually created the icon for the marker and avoid the issue with the big clickable area around it?

I have also tried the implementation described [here](http://www.ugopiemontese.eu/2014/06/18/custom-markers-for-android-google-maps-api-v2/), basically the drawTextToBitmap() method:

```
private Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(@DrawableRes int backgroundRes, String text) {
        Resources resources = getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, backgroundRes);
        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = bitmap.getConfig();

        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // SET FONT COLOR (e.g. WHITE -> rgb(255,255,255))
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        // SET FONT SIZE (e.g. 15)
        paint.setTextSize((int) (15 * scale));
        // SET SHADOW WIDTH, POSITION AND COLOR (e.g. BLACK)
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.BLACK);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;
        canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

But it doesn't work as expected, because my text is bigger than the background, and I also don't know how to add an resource to the left of the text.

This is the implementation for IconGenerator I'm using:

```
private BitmapDescriptor getBitmapDescriptorForProduct(@NonNull final MyCustomObject product, boolean isActive) {
    if (product.shouldDisplayWithLabel) {
        // We use an custom layout for displaying markers on the map
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View view =
                LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.my_custom_label, null);

        // Get the text view which will display the text 
        TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        // Set the left drawable if needed
        label.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(product.shouldDisplayWithDrawable ? R.drawable.my_custom_drawable : 0, 0,
                                                      0, 0);
        // Set the text for the label
        label.setText(product.label);
        label.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_custom_background);

        // Set the layout for the icon
        mIconGenerator.setContentView(view); // set the custom layout

        // We don't want the default background
        mIconGenerator.setBackground(null);
        // Disable the content padding as we handle it in the view and in the 9patch resources
        mIconGenerator.setContentPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

        // Make the icon and create the BitmapDescriptor necessary for the marker creation
        Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon);
    } else {
        // Lazy initialization for the normal markers
        if (null == simpleMarkerIcon) {
            simpleMarkerIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_simple_marker);
        }

        // Reuse the bitmap for the simple markers that will be displayed on the map.
        return simpleMarkerIcon;
    }
}
```

**LE:**
@Harpreet, this how the marker icon will look like using your solution:

[image: Marker icon using @Harpreet solution]

As you can see, the properties of the view are not displayed correctly in the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels,
                displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(),
                view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Note:- Just fill **Context** and add your complete custom created view/layout as an object of **View**

It'll help you.

Comment: It seems this method is very memory intensive and I get OOM exception 99% of times running this.

Comment: I've also added an SS with the result of the bitmap using your method.

Comment: You need to use Google Clustering too, if you have a numerous markers to show on map at same time.

Comment: The design of the application doesn't rely on clustering, thus it isn't an option for me currently. I've updated the question and included the implementation for IconGenerator. This is very close to what I need, but the touch area of the marker is very big.

Comment: Hi @IonutNegru Does that helps? By any chance, were you able to find the solution. i am stuck into same situation. Thanks.